# Inscribed hypersphere of a simplex

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, euclidean-geometry, matrix-equations, computational-geometry

What is the formula to calculate the radius $r$ and center $x$ of the inscribed hypersphere from the $n+1$ vertices of an arbitrary simplex in $R^n$? A matrix based solution is preferred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given vertices $v_0,\ldots, v_n$, let
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 
\colon\colon & w_0^T & \colon\colon  & d_0 \\
\colon\colon  & w_1^T & \colon\colon & d_1 \\
 & \vdots &  & \vdots \\
\colon\colon  & w_n^T & \colon\colon & d_n \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} 
\colon\colon  & \colon\colon &  & \colon\colon \\
v_0 & v_1 & \cdots & v_n \\
\colon\colon  & \colon\colon &  & \colon\colon \\
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
$$
with $w_i\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $d_i\in\mathbb{R}$.

We show that
$$
r=\frac{1}{\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} \left\|w_i\right\|_2}
$$
and
$$
x=\frac{\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} \left\|w_i\right\|_2\,v_i}{\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} \left\|w_i\right\|_2}
$$
From the definition of the $w_i$, we can see that $w_j^Tx + d_j=0$ is the equation for the hyperplane that contains all vertices of the simplex except $v_j$. Furthermore, we have $w_j^Tv_j = 1-d_j$.

We must now verify that $x$ has distance $r$ from that hyperplane, i.e. we must verify that 
$$
w_j^Tx+d_j=r\,\|w_j\|_2\;\;\forall\;j\in\{0,\ldots,n\}
$$
We find
$$
w_j^Tx+d_j = w_j^T\frac{\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} \left\|w_i\right\|_2\,v_i}{\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} \left\|w_i\right\|_2} + d_j=
\frac{\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} \left\|w_i\right\|_2\,w_j^Tv_i}{\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} \left\|w_i\right\|_2} +d_j \\
=\frac{\sum\limits_{i\neq j} \left\|w_i\right\|_2\,w_j^Tv_i \;+\; \left\|w_j\right\|_2\,w_j^Tv_j}{\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} \left\|w_i\right\|_2} +d_j \\
=\frac{-\,\sum\limits_{i\neq j} \left\|w_i\right\|_2\,d_j \;+\; \left\|w_j\right\|_2\,(1-d_j)}{\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} \left\|w_i\right\|_2} +d_j \\
=\frac{-\,\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} \left\|w_i\right\|_2\,d_j \;+\; \left\|w_j\right\|_2}{\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} \left\|w_i\right\|_2} +d_j \\
=-d_j \;+\; \frac{ \left\|w_j\right\|_2}{\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} \left\|w_i\right\|_2} +d_j \\
= r\,\|w_j\|_2
$$
We can see that we are on the correct side of each of the hyperplanes, because $x$ is a convex combination of the $v_i$.

In order to generalize this for $k$-simplices, we need some conditions to enforce that our vectors $w_i$ are in the same subspace as the differences $v_{j_1}-v_{j_2}$. We can achieve this e.g. by choosing $n-k$ vectors $a_1,\ldots,a_{n-k}$ which are perpendicular to the subspace that contains all the differences $v_{j_1}-v_{j_2}$, and then ensure that the $w_i$ are perpendicular to the $a_i$:
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 
\colon\colon & w_0^T & \colon\colon  & d_0 \\
 & \vdots &  & \vdots \\
\colon\colon  & w_k^T & \colon\colon & d_k \\
\colon\colon & b_1^T & \colon\colon  & c_1 \\
 & \vdots &  & \vdots \\
\colon\colon  & b_{n-k}^T & \colon\colon & c_{n-k} \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} 
\colon\colon  &   & \colon\colon & \colon\colon  &   & \colon\colon  \\
v_0 & \cdots & v_k & a_1 & \cdots & a_{n-k} \\
\colon\colon  &   & \colon\colon & \colon\colon  &   & \colon\colon \\
1 &  \cdots & 1 & 0 &  \cdots & 0
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
$$
The radius and centre still are
$$
r=\frac{1}{\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k} \left\|w_i\right\|_2}
$$
and
$$
x=\frac{\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k} \left\|w_i\right\|_2\,v_i}{\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k} \left\|w_i\right\|_2}
$$
In practice, the vectors $a_i$ would not be actually computed. Instead, we can use the $QR$-decomposition to obtain the results:
$$
QR=Q\begin{pmatrix} R_1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix} Q_1 & Q_2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} R_1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix} 
& & \\
v_0-v_k & \cdots & v_{k-1}-v_k \\
& &
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $Q_1$ contains the first $k$ columns of $Q$, and $Q_2$ contains the last $n-k$ columns. Then we have
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
w_0^T \\ \vdots \\ w_{k-1}^T
\end{pmatrix}
= R_1^{-1}Q_1^T
$$
or 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
& & \\
w_0 & \cdots & w_{k-1} \\
& &
\end{pmatrix}
= Q_1\left(R_1^{-1}\right)^T
$$
and 
$$
w_k=-\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1} w_i
$$

Comment: Nice solution by the way. You can also compute the matrix as $M=\begin{bmatrix}v_0-v_n & \cdots & v_{n-1}-v_n \end{bmatrix}^{-1}$, then the last $w_i$ is the norm of the sum of the rows of $M$, i.e. $||w_n|| = ||M_0+M_1+...+M_{n-1}||$. This way you reduce the matrix from size $(N+1) \times (N+1)$ to $N \times N$, which speeds up the inversion.

Comment: I guess you calculate $d_i$ values to use them in your proof.

Comment: That's correct. They are required for the proof, only.

Comment: Is it possible to further generalize to a $k$-simplex in $n$-dimensional space, where $k \le n$? If I clone a columun to make the matrix square (representing a degenerate simplex), it becomes singular.

Comment: @plasmacel I have added a description of the generalization for $k$-simplices. For practical use, this can probably be simplified (the vectors $b_i$ and the numbers $c_i$ are not required at all.)

Comment: Interesting. When $k=n-1$ (which is the most common case), then we need 1 perpendicular vector, which can be produced by the $n$-dimensional cross product of the $k$ difference vectors. For $k < n-1$ I have no idea.

Comment: Actually you can still use the $n$-dimensional cross product $\star(u_1 \wedge \ldots \wedge u_{n-1})$ when $k < n - 1$ to get the perpendicular $w_i$ vectors. The cross product needs a set of $n-1$ vectors. The $k$-simplex provides $k$ non-collinear difference vectors of the set. The remaining $(n-1)-k$ vectors of the set can be any vector non-collinear with the others. On the other hand the column echelon form of the matrix made from the vertices doesn't seem to work (or I misunderstood what you mean).

Comment: I added my proposal for the calculation in practice by means of the $QR$ decomposition.

Comment: Thanks, it was very helpful! In the meantime I figured out that you actually compute the pseudo-inverse with QR decomposition. This is the same as $(M^T M)^{-1}M^T$, where $M = \begin{bmatrix} v_0 - v_k & \cdots & v_{k-1}-v_k\end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 2):

Given vertices $v_0, v_1, \dots, v_n$, let $S_i$ for $0 \le i \le n$ be the $(n-1)$-dimensional volume of the face of the simplex opposite $v_i$.

Each face, together with the center $x$, spans a smaller simplex whose base has $(n-1$)-volume $S_i$ and whose height is $r$, so its volume is $\frac1n r S_i$ (by analogy with the formulas $A = \frac12bh$ and $V = \frac13Bh$ in $2$ and $3$ dimensions). These $n+1$ simplices partition the original simplex, and their total volume $\frac1n rS_0 + \frac1n rS_1 + \dots + \frac1n rS_n$ is also the volume $V$ of the original simplex. So we have $$r = \frac{nV}{S_0 + S_1 + \dots + S_n}.$$ This argument also shows that the barycentric coordinates of the incenter $x$ are proportional to $[S_0 : S_1 : \dots : S_n]$, so we can find $x$ by the linear combination $$x= \frac{S_0 v_0 + S_1 v_1 + \dots + S_n v_n}{S_0 + S_1 + \dots + S_n}.$$

It remains to compute the volume $V$ and the $(n-1)$-volumes $S_i$. By an extension of the $2$-dimensional formula, we have $$V = \frac1{n!} \left|\det \begin{bmatrix} 1 & - & v_0 & - \\ 1 & - & v_1 & - \\ \vdots & &\vdots &  \\ 1 & - & v_n & - \end{bmatrix} \right|$$ where each row holds $1$ followed by the coordinates of one of the vertices.

For the $S_i$, I have a method that works, but I'm not convinced is the easiest. Given $n$ points $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n$ in $\mathbb R^n$, we can find a direction $w$ such that $\langle w, v_i - v_1 \rangle = 0$ for $i=2, \dots, n$, by solving a system of linear equations. Then the volume of the simplex spanned by $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n$ and $v_1 + w$ will be $\frac1n \|w\| S_0$, since the final added direction is perpendicular to the face of the simplex. So we can compute the volume of the simplex by the earlier formula, and then divide by $\frac{\|w\|}{n}$ to get $S_0$.

Repeat for the other faces, excluding a different vertex $v_i$ every time, to compute $S_1, \dots, S_n$.

Comment: The scaling factor $\frac{1}{n}$ in the volume formula is wrong, it should be $\frac{1}{n!}$.

Comment: I could have sworn that I've already fixed that mistake. Huh. Well, it's fixed now.